# I want terraform commands in a directory without changing to directory

Tags: terraform

Say, I have mydir directory, I don't want to do a cd mydir and run terraform get/init/plan/apply. I want to pass it as a argument.

For eg:

terraform get -pwd mydir

Answer (score 0):

terraform get

E.g: terraform get mydir